# reassign variables value through second file (including DiscordJS)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm relatively new to both JavaScript and Discord.JS and I'm stuck on a little thing that is giving me a serious headache.
The bot should be able to do the following:

1. store a message (after a certain prefix) in a variable
2. pass it to an array in a JSON file
3. where the message is converted to a (given) number and stored in a new variable in the first JS file.

I explicitly do not ask for any finished code (including code skeletons), as I cannot learn anything from it and it would be useless in the end. All I want are maybe tips on how to realize this. :)

I hope the whole thing is at least somehow understandable, if not, I would be happy to explain details in more detail!

Comment: Can you specify what have you tried so far?

Comment: By "storing a message" you mean to store only its content or the whole message object?